# Save Word document as a filename generated from tabled info contained within the document

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am looking to enable Word to save with a file name using data contained within the document.

At the top of the document (an airline release letter), there is a table containing  2 columns with 3 rows containing alpha in one column and alpha-numeric data in column 2.

```
Column 1,
Cell 1: AETC; Cell 2: MAWB; Cell 3: HAWB

Column 2,
Cell 1: 80123; Cell 2, 0161234567; Cell 3: 00112345678
```

Basically, the first column will be the static labels for the variable data to be entered into column 2.

From all this, I want to generate a save-as file name: `AETC80123_MAWB0161234567_HAWB00112345678_ReleaseLetter.doc`

I've barely scratched the surface of VBA as I am more an operations supervisor than a techie so I'm not certain if this is even possible.

Any help/direction/copy-paste coding (if it's super easy and of little trouble) would be awesome!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to work it all out in detail for, nor is this tested at all (just written out of my head), but this should give a hint how you read cell content in a Word document:

```
' Set tbl to first table in document
Dim tbl As Table
Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(0)

Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim val As String
Dim filename As String
filename = ""

For r = 1 To tbl.Rows.Count
    For c = 1 To tbl.Columns.Count
        ' Get text in cell
        val = tbl.Cell(r, c).Range.Text
        ' and append to string or whatever
        filename = filename & val & "_"
    Next c
Next r
```

Finally, save your document using

```
ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=filename
```

Check [this microsoft site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220734%28v=office.11%29.aspx) for more information about SaveAs parameters.